# MongoDB split data in more Collection

Tags: php, mongodb

I have one collection (CollectionA) .
in this collection there are data of more experiment.

I want create one collection for each experiment:
Collection1, Collection2 ...

There is a mode? without losing data?

ps. I can interfacing MongoDB with php

---

Add information:

I have a Collection with MANY MANY data of experiment (experimentA,ExperimentB,...).

I want split this collection in more collection one for each Experiment.

(a kind of partition)

---

```
Collection NAME = testCollection
```

in this Collection there is "experiment" field 
(ex. ExperimentA , ExperimentB , ...)

COLLECTION OUTPUT REQUIRED :

```
testCollection_ExperimentA

testCollection_ExperimentB
```

Need more information?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB enables easy to use **Split** method.

While running the following command:

```
db.runCommand( { split : "db.collectionName", find : { 'experimentName' : "A" } } )
```

The split command identifies the chunk in the db.collectionName. Then the command splits it into two chunks.
You can do it as many times as you need.

You can read the full documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/split/).

Comment: Thank's for the answer. This comand create a new Collection with data (experimentName = A) ?